# Is there a random variable $X$ for which $P [µx - 2σ ≤ X ≤ µx + 2σx] = 0.6$?

Tags: probability, chebyshev-function

Is there a random variable X for which

$$P [µx - 2σ ≤ X ≤ µx + 2σx] = 0.6$$
I have tried this:
$$P|X- µx ≤  2σx|=P((X- µx)² ≤ 4(σx)²) ≥ 1- 1/r²= 1- 1/4= 3/4 ≠ 0.6.$$
So there is no random variable that meets this probability.

Comment: What you have done is correct but you should change $\frac  3 4 \neq 0.6$ to $\frac 3 4 >0.6$

Comment: Thank you so much!